# Table View Cell Text Color with Multicolored Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am wanting to use a certain image as the background view of my table view.  The problem is that the image has multiple colors so I need to be able to change the text color as the table view is scrolled but I'm not sure how to go about that.  The problem I have with this option is the fact that the text would be multiple different colors when looking at the table view and that isn't very appealing.  What other options do I have?

Here is the image I'm wanting to use as the background view.

[image]

Comment: for changing the UItableView cell label text color check for the its y position and and then change the color according too

Comment: How about dropping shadow around text?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use image filter to make it gray scale image, sephia or monochrome image.
This is for reference. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html